# How can I automatically queue when launching TF2?

Tags: team-fortress-2

Every time I start TF2, I do the exact same things:

1. Launch the shortcut
2. Wait for the screen to load (PC is useless meanwhile, can't <kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>TAB</kbd>)
3. Click "Find New Games"
4. Click "Search" so I'm in the queue (map options are saved)
5. <kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>TAB</kbd> to windows until the TF2 icon flashes and I know I finally got a game.

How can I automate steps 1-4 so I can just launch the game and it automatically starts looking for the best game?

Comment: You can press ctrl alt del and click task manager, which will focus the task manager and bring up the task bar, where you can do other stuff while it loads. Most of the time the windows key or Windows + D works though.

Answer (score 1):

In theory you could run the console command `+OpenMatchmakingLobby Casual` in the TF2 launch options, which would at least save you one click, but setting this as a launch option causes TF2 to crash on my PC. If anyone out there knows a way to get this to work, this might become a partial answer.

Comment: Aha, that's the direction I was looking for. Could this be scripted into autoexec or something? Aliased?

Comment: Where did you find this `OpenMatchmakingLobby` command? Is there some kind of TF2 console documentation or API I'm missing?